# What is the difference between glu functions and mat.h functions from Interactive Computer Graphics?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, shader

I am a newbie at using shaders and tried to make ModelViewProjection matrix for vertices. But I have different scenes when I use built-in functions and when I use functions provided by mat.h from book Interactive Computer Graphics 6th Edition.
So here the code:

```
//In main.cpp
gluLookAt(0.0 , 0.0 , 5.0, 
              0.0 , 0.0 , -1.0,
              0.0f , 1.0f , 0.0f);
 gluPerspective(45,ratio,1,1000);

 //In Vertex Shader
 gl_Position =    gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
```

And the result:
[image]

.
But when I write this:

```
//In main.cpp
projectionMatrix = Perspective( 45.0  , ratio, 1, 1000);
modelMatrix = mat4(1.0);
vec4 eye = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 1.0);
vec4 at = vec4(0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0);
vec4 up = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
viewMatrix = LookAt(eye, at, up);
// In vertex Shader
 gl_Position =   ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix  * ModelMatrix * gl_Vertex;
```

I got this:

[image]

Do anyone know what gets wrong? 
P.S. I also tried to convert degrees to radians, but it gets much worse and I do not think that mat.h use radians.

Comment: Please include your _results_ in the question itself, and not in 3rd party links.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: Which third party links do you mean? If you are taking about the images, then they were at `i.stack.imgur.com`. Users at that rep-level can't include images themself.

Answer (score 0):

First, it depends on your vector which side you need to multiply it. If you want to consider your vector as a column vector , than multiplying it from the left side is fine.(First example) But also if you are consider the vector as a row vector, you need to transpose the matrices and multiply the vector from the right hand side, in the reverse order.

Try this in your shader:
`gl_Position =   gl_Vertex * ModelMatrix * ViewMatrix  *  ProjectionMatrix;`

Answering your questin: Why does it give you different results? Because maybe the book is considering the vectors as a row vectors.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it. It didn't solve the problem. It just shows pink window. And as I understand, the mat.h's functions are same as glm's, but I am not sure.